# Sendmail mqueue deferred (list.dsbl.org)

Tags: sendmail, spam

Hi I have a issue with a mailserver configured with sendmail.

In mailq  I have many entrys with:

> (dnsbl map: lookup (254.0.168.192.list.dsbl.org.): deferred)

Thanks.

Comment: It appears you have a DNS-based Email Blacklist configured, and when it performs a lookup on 192.168.0.254, a listing is returned and the email is being deferred. However, when I perform the same lookup, I don't receive a listing. Can you provide that part of your configuration file, please?

Comment: Could you post full version of the log entry and all log entries with the same queue-id?

Comment: What is your question? Have you searched on Google for "dnsbl map: lookup", and what does that tell you about dnsbl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The DSBL blackhole list went dead almost five years ago.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Sender_Blackhole_List) You should remove it from your configuration.